Kronecker product from vector half
I need to compute $D_p^\top(\Sigma\otimes \Sigma)D_p$, where $D_p$ is the duplication matrix and $\Sigma$ is a $p\times p$ symmetric matrix. When $p$ is large, the kronecker product becomes very large ($p^2\times p^2$) and I would like to find a way to bypass it and only use the vector half of $\Sigma$, since it contains all the information already, and get directly to the final $p(p+1)/2\times p(p+1)/2$ result. Is this possible?
I have tried to find some sort of transformation matrix which does a linear combination of the elements of $\mbox{vech}(\Sigma)\mbox{vech}(\Sigma)^\top$, which includes all possible products, but I cannot figure out how to compute this transformation. I am wondering if there is some known matrix, analogous to the duplication matrix, which can do this job. I did not find this in the literature.
The matrix is assumed to be sparse if this helps.
